# Django Tabular Formset

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

This is on Django 1.5.

I have what appears to be a simple problem, but which turned out to be really complicated in practice. So I'm working on a job application site, and I have 2 models:

- Applicant
- Skill

The 2 models are related through a through model, ApplicantSkillScore. So it looks something like:

```
class Applicant(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    skills = models.ManyToManyField(Skills, through='ApplicantSkillScore')

class Skill(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class ApplicantSkillScore(models.Model):
    applicant = models.ForeignKey(Applicant)
    skill = models.ForeignKey(Skill)
    score = models.FloatField(_("Score"))
```

Now what I want to do is to render a table-based form to enter an applicant's skill score, like this:

```
 -----------------------------------------------
|           |            |        |             |
| Applicant | Javascript | Python | Objective-C |
|-----------+------------+--------+-------------|
| John      |  5.0       | <Form> |    <Form>   |
| Jane      |  <Form>    | 6.7    |    <Form>   |
 -----------------------------------------------
```

The idea is that:

1. The applicants and skills are derived dynamically, from the respective models. (If the skills were hard-coded fields, this would be 10000x easier.)
2. If the applicant's skill score is present, display a prepopulated form. Otherwise, display an empty form.

Is there an elegant way in Django to render a form like this?

Answer (score 0):

I think the way to go is to use inline formsets.

You could then render all the Applicant and their associated skill score as a formset.

> 1. The applicants and skills are derived dynamically, from the respective models. (If the skills were hard-coded fields, this would
>      be 10000x easier.)

Basically you just want to create a parent model object and its associated children (ApplicantSkillScore). That's where [inline formsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/forms/modelforms/#inline-formsets) are the solution because they allow you to have a view to create/modify your Applicant model and the other models linked to it with a foreign key.

> 2. If the applicant's skill score is present, display a prepopulated form. Otherwise, display an empty form.

That's just a matter of rendering your forms in your templates. With the inline formsets, it will act just like a normal form and display the data if any or just an empty form. Up to you how you want to present it.

I've used this example to get started : [inline formset with class based view example](http://kevindias.com/writing/django-class-based-views-multiple-inline-formsets/)